# Proof of additive inverse of $(-a)^2$

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove that $(-a)^2$ has as additive inverse $-(a^2)$.
It looks trivial, but if I constrain myself to the use of the field axioms it is not so trivial to me. I think one could try that by using a proof by contradiction. I.e. assume that $-(a^2)$ is not the inverse and then showing that that leads to a contradiction.
So if $-(a^2)$ is not the inverse then it is either smaller or greater than $(-a)^2$. But I am not sure how to prove the contradiction from here.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it myself.
Let us calculate $$(-a)^2+(-a^2)=(-a)(-a)+(-a)a$$
Then by distributivity
$$(-a)(-a)+(-a)a=(-a+a)(-a)$$
But since -a is the inverse of a:
$$(-a+a)(-a)=0a=0$$
Therefore we have shown directly that (-a)^2 is the inverse of -a^2 and viceversa.

Comment: You have two statements that are not commonly part of the field axioms: $-a^2 = (-a)a$ and $0a=0$.  Typically $0a=0$ is one of the first propositions proven from the field axioms so I might give that a pass, but I'm not convinced the former identity is less complicated than the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thank for pointing that out. I already saw the proof of the second statement in my textbook. but I am not so sure about the first statement. How do I show that?

Comment: You'd need to show $a\cdot a + (-a)\cdot a = 0$, for which the proof has the same method as your answer (distributivity followed by $0a=0$)