# Proof from field axioms that $(-a)a=-a^2$

Tags: field-theory

I asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4505800/proof-of-additive-inverse-of-a2) and answered it by using that $$(-a)a=-(a^2)$$
But Brian pointed out that this identity is more complicated than what I want to prove. So it is necessary to also show this identity from the field axioms. How do I show it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $(-a)a + a^2 = (-a + a)a = 0a = 0$, which implies $(-a)a = -(a^2)$ due to uniqueness.

The identity $0x=0$ is a standard exercise.